# Getting notified about a new block on the Monero blockchain

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, mymonero, monero-wallet-rpc, monerod-commands

Is there any method, other than polling, to subscribe to new blocks being published on the Monero network? I want to get notified whenever a new block is published on the network on my app.

Answer (score 2):

The current Monero release allows you to call a program in those cases:

When a block in added to the blockchain, you can trigger a command using monerod's `--block-notify` option.

When a transaction is received by the wallet (both when seen in the txpool and after its first confirmation), you can trigger a command using monero-wallet-{cli,rpc}' `--tx-notify` option.

Both of those options take as parameter a program and optional parameters. Every instance of %s will be replaced by the block hash or transaction hash which triggered the notification. Note that this is a program and optional parameters, and not a shell command, if you want redirection or pipes, you'll have to call a shell (eg, `--tx-notify bash -e 'echo %s >> /tmp/hashes'`). Parsing is limited, so you can't use quotes and backslashes to escape spaces. If you need complex parsing, write a script to do it and call the script.

Answer (score 0):

No. Polling is the only way. You only need to poll once every couple of minutes at most though.

Comment: Can't websocket be used for the same?

Comment: No. The daemon doesn't implement a websocket server. Only RPC.